# C# detect last `Enter` in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a lot of string with following pattern(format):

```
aaaaaaa aa aa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bb bbbbb bbb bb
ccccc c cc ccc 

XXXX XX 
zzzzzz zzz
```

OR:

```
aaaaaaa aa aa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bb bbbbb bbb bb
ccccc c cc ccc

dddd  dddd 

XXXX XX 
zzzzzz zzz
```

OR :

```
aaaaaaa aa aa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bb bbbbb bbb bb
ccccc c cc ccc

dddddddd


eeeee

XXXX XX 
zzzzzz zzz
```

I want to replace `XXXX XX` with `YYYY`. I think I need to detect last`Enter`in string and do the operation. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused: if you want to replace `XXXX XX`, why do you want to look for the last line break. Why don't you look for `XXXX XX`? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: btw: `yourText.LastIndexOf('\n')`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, because the title of your question is different than the problem statement inside the question.

Comment: Maybe this `(.*)\n.*$`  [here at regex100](https://regex101.com/r/ULIVIw/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this. If the string in question is always on the second to last line, I'd split the string into an array of strings, a single string per line. Then find out how many lines (strings in array) there are. The object of interest is this number -2. Then replace this string with YYYY.

**EDIT:**

```
var result = Regex.Split(input, "\r\n|\r|\n");
int len = result.Length;
result[len - 2] = "YYYY";
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Comment: You should provide an example for this - it would work, but it's not a very good answer without something more specific, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the pattern, here's an example with Regex:

```
\b\S{4}\s\S{2}\b
```

You could use this regex like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b\S{4}\s\S{2}\b");
var result = regex.Replace(inputString, "YYYY");
```

It looks for a word boundary (e.g. a return), then four non-whitespace characters, then one whitespace character, two non-whitespace characters and a word boundary again. It should do what you want.

However, depending on your input it might be a better idea to use this regex:

```
\b\S{4} \S{2}\b
```

So I replaced the whitespace character with an actual space character. Of course it could still happen that one of your characters is counted as a word boundary, then again I'd have to see an example of your input.

Here's an example of how it works:

[image: example]

It's in the C# interactive, which works pretty much the same as normal C#.

**EDIT**

As I realized that your pattern relevant line ends with a space, you could use this pattern as well:

```
\b\S{4} \S{2}\b\n
```

Which would probably work even better. However you'd have to replace it with `"YYYY\n"` then.

Comment: It's just a pattern.

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It just replace last enter with `YYYY`.

Comment: As it works with your pattern, in that case I must ask for an example of your input.

Comment: @distance I edited my answer, so that it should work even in the strangest of cases now.

Comment: None of you'r solution worked with a string like this: `asf asdf asf asfsad
sdfsdf asdf asdf asd fas fasd fas

xxxxx
zzzzz z z zzz`

Comment: unfortunately I cant send you a sample string

Comment: @distance your example has nothing to do with your pattern anymore, has it? But if you can't provide a sample, it'd probably the best if you read yourself into Regex.